# redis-commander error events.js:292 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, database, redis, node-redis

What I have done:

```
> docker pull redis
    
> docker run --name redis -p 7379:6379 -d redis
    
> npm install -g redis-commander
```

** Error Raising at ***

```
> redis-commander --redis-port 7379
```

I have installed the redis-commander globally on my computer and added it to the docker.
when I try to run the redis server I'm getting the below error.

**ERROR**

```
C:\Users\>redis-commander --redis-port 7379

Using scan instead of keys
No Save: false
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1498:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1340:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 8081
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and for the life of me couldn't figure it out. Redis commander defaults to port 8081 and I already had a package running on that port. To resolve it, edit the file default.json in the redis-commander folder (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\redis-commander\config for me), and change the port from 8081 to anything else that you want to use, e.g. 8085 etc. Then relaunch the app.